# Java Class and Interface Name Collision

Tags: java, class, interface

```
interface A {
  void print();
}

class A implements A {
  public void print() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    A a=new A();
    a.print();
  }
}
```

When i am using this code then it is saying "duplicate class:A". Why so? Can I not have same class and interface name

Comment: "_Can I not have same class and interface name_" No, not like this. Even if you could, you shouldn't want to.

Comment: You should give classes and interfaces (and methods and variables) meaningful names.

Comment: An interface *is* a special type of abstract class.  That’s why you can write `System.out.println(Runnable.class)` and `System.out.println(Class.forName("java.lang.Runnable"))`.

Comment: To the people downvoting, voting to close: this is a legitimate question, and (according to my search) not a duplicate.  The fact that it indicates that the OP has misunderstood something pretty fundamental about classes and interfaces (that they are named in the same namespace) does not make it a bad Question.  (OK: if the OP could have researched this better.  However, consider that SO is supposed to be a place to find Answers ... and there wasn't one here for this Question.)

Answer (score 7):

You can't have a class and an interface with the same name because the Java language doesn't allow it.

First of all, it's ambiguous.  If you declare a variable like this:

```
A a;
```

What is the type of that variable?  Is it the class, or the interface?

Second, compiled Java code is stored in `.class` files named after the class or interface defined in the file.  An interface named `A` and a class named `A` would both compile to a file named `A.class`.  You can't have two files with the same name in the same folder.

The error message says "duplicate class" because Java internally treats an interface as a special kind of class.

Answer (score 2):

The fully qualified name of a class and interface consist of the package name and the class/interface name only.

So if your package name is `com.foo.bar`, both the interface and the class names would be: `com.foo.bar.A`

Under different packages you can have the same names of course.